# error: cannot find symbol variable text1 in two_line_list_item

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having trouble populating the ListView with Firebase. Haven't added any extra views in ListView. Application crashes while opening. Firebase's data storage seemed to work pretty fine before adding the ListView.

#### build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 24
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Firebase ref;
    ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    List<ChatMessage> messages;
    ListView messagesList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        final EditText textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesList);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        ref = new Firebase("https://nanochat-cc415.firebaseio.com/");

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ChatMessage chat = new ChatMessage("Fatima",textMessage.getText().toString());
                ref.push().setValue(chat);
                textMessage.setText("");
            }
        });

        messages = new LinkedList<>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, messages)
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(view == null) {
                    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, parent, false);
                }
                    ChatMessage chat = messages.get(position);
                    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(chat.getName());
                    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(chat.getMessage());

                return view;
            }
        };

        messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);

        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ChatMessage chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                messages.add(chat);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing `R.id.text1` with `android.R.id.text1` and same as `R.id.text2` with `android.R.id.text2`.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked! 

And Thanks for answering my first question here on stackoverflow!